# I want to configure site collection with 2 server when the first down the site still run with the second server --HOW by NLB or what?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I want to configure site collection with 2 server when the first down the site still run with the  second server --HOW by NLB or what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, network load balancing is the technology to use in this case.

For multiple SharePoint farm servers, any web applications created will be rolled out to all servers in the farm, so as long as you have network load balancing configured in front of the web front end servers, if one server goes down, the other server should take the load.

Note that the built-in Windows NLB is fairly brain-dead, but can be useful if no other technologies are available. If you have a hardware load balancer, use that instead, or consider using Microsoft's Application Request routing (ARR) module for IIS as this works well, but requires a separate server to run ARR on.

Comment: Dear Andy , Thanks A lot , I configure 2 server with farm and run the same services in the two server then I configure NLB .

Comment: I cant add additional server for ARR

Comment: SharePoint service applications automatically internally load balance themselves if the service is run one more than one server. The content web applications are the ones that require NLB.

Answer (score 0):

For high availability case, you should also be thinking of service applications, timer jobs etc. For instance, if your site heavily depends on Enterprise Search, you should distribute relevant search components to multiple servers.